# How do I retrieve my deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

About an hour ago, I asked a question, and decided to delete it. Now, I want to undelete it, but I can't find it. Is it permanently deleted? If not, how do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 3):

> ## How can I undelete one of my posts?
>
> Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. However, self-deleted questions cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first. Self-deleted answers can be edited by the author without undeleting. Normally, if your deleted post is not self-deleted, you can't undelete it yourself (though you may be able to vote to undelete). An exception: if an answer is deleted from Low Quality review queue by "Recommend Deletion" votes, without three trusted users voting to delete, then it [can be undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/259867) by the author.
>
> If your post was deleted by [trusted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted - politely asking for this on Meta may attract the necessary votes if you make a good case for why the question should be restored.
>
> If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag one of your other posts and write a note in the "other" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion.
>
> Note: deleted questions do not appear in search results, so you if you wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have saved the URL somewhere. Users with 10K reputation and up can also mark questions as a "favorite" and find them later from the Favorites tab on their profiles. Only moderators can search for deleted posts, nobody else.
>
> Deleted posts that are *no more than 60 days old* (since the creation date) are listed under ["recent deleted questions" or "recent deleted answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/).

― [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)